# Cart items will not be deleted in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer

I searched a lot but none of the solutions worked for me, I am trying to delete an Item from `observer` but if there is only one item in cart it works with `removeAllItems()` but if there are more than one items then it doesn't work, below is snippet from my code for observer `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`:

```
// get the product data and product options chosen
$transport = $observer->getTransport();

// get the current product
$product = $observer->getProduct();

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            // get all the cart items
$items = $cart->getAllItems();

// if item count is greater than 1 then remove current product only
if (count($items) > 1) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $product->getId()) {
            try {
                  $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                  $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();

                  if($item->getParentItemId()) {
                      $cart->removeItem($item->getParentItemId())->save();
                  }

              } catch (Exception $e) {
                  Mage::log('Failed to remove item from cart'.$e.'.');
              }
          }
    }
    $cart->setCartWasUpdated(true);
} else { // else every item

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $product->getId())
        {

            try {
//                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                  $cart->removeAllItems();
                  $cart->save();
                  $cart->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                  Mage::log('Failed to remove item from cart'.$e.'.');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`else` part works (removes item) but mini cart shows 1 product selected and if you hover on it to see the item it show no products in cart. `If` part doesn't work at all.

Comment: Do you get error message in your log?

Comment: No I do not get any error messages..

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I enabled log from admin so there are log messages from other module.

Comment: Ho do you get your value for `$product`? Please add code as you have used `$product->getId()` but there is no code where the variable is defined.

Comment: I have updated the code...

Comment: I have checked the code and `if` part is also working. If you add a product which is already in cart, then that product gets removed. Isn't it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55326/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-sagar-guhe).

Answer (score 0):

For the single item, I am sure you can use this function to remove the item from cart.

```
$quote->removeAllItems();
$quote->save();
```

This is the working code for the above question.

```
public function removeItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $productId = $_SESSION['prescription']['product_id'];
    $result = $_SESSION['prescription']['result'];
if($result == 0)
{
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $items = $cart->getItems();
    $itemCount = count($items);
    if($itemCount > 1)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $i++;
            if($i == $itemCount)
            {
                if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId)
                {
                    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                    $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId)
            {
                try{
                    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                    $quote->removeAllItems();
                    $quote->save();
                }catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    Mage::log('Failed to remove item from cart'.$e.'.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is `prescription` in `$_SESSION` var?

Comment: I think you have syntax error in your code, outer `if` or `function` is not cosed

Comment: This is not removing first product

Answer (score 0):

I reference this answer.

event bind `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

code:

```
public function removeItem($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $productId = $event->getQuoteItem()->getProduct()->getId();
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $items = $cart->getItems();
    $itemCount = count($items);
    if($itemCount > 0)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId)
            {
                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                $item->isDeleted(true);
                $cart->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```